# Problems with deallocation of double pointer and pointer

Tags: c

Hi everyone i have some problems in my code:

This is a matrix allocation function:

```
matrix_type** matrix_allocation(MATRIX* matrix, int* rows_size, int* cols_size)
//this function allocates dynamically a matrix and verify its allocation
{
    int i;
    matrix->n_rows=0;
    matrix->n_cols=0;
    matrix->pp_matrix=(matrix_type**)calloc(*rows_size,sizeof(matrix_type*));
    i=0;
    while(i<*rows_size)
    {
        matrix->pp_matrix[i]=calloc(*cols_size,sizeof(matrix_type));
        i++;
    }
    matrix->n_rows=*rows_size;
    matrix->n_cols=*cols_size;
    return matrix->pp_matrix;
}
```

This is my deallocation function:

```
void matrix_deallocation(MATRIX* matrix)
//this function deallocates a matrix
{
    int i;
    i=0;
    while(i<matrix->n_cols)
    {
        free(matrix->pp_matrix[i]);
        i++;
    }
    free(matrix->pp_matrix);
}
```

where the `MATRIX` struct is

```
typedef int matrix_type;
typedef struct{
    int n_rows;
    int n_cols;
    matrix_type** pp_matrix;
}MATRIX;
```

How i call deallocation function in main:

```
matrix_deallocation(&table);
```

This function deallocate only half matrix, Why?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKcSa.png)

Comment: Have you heard of `for` loops - makes the code more readable than using `while` loops

Comment: @Simone TheAlmighty Cicerello  Did you allocate the matrix by rows or by columns?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you mean the following

```
void matrix_deallocation(MATRIX* matrix)
//this function deallocates a matrix
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < matrix->n_rows; i++ )
    //                           ^^^^^^ 
    {
        free( matrix->pp_matrix[i] );
    }
    free(matrix->pp_matrix);
}
```

Comment: Good point, but the screenshot not so informative; both the number of rows and columns is 4.

Comment: @Codor I did not investigate the screenshot but at first glance it seems that the matrix has five columns.